# Making line graph from multiple columns data in R

Tags: multiple-columns, linechart

Here is my data
| Country | Pop 2021 | Pop 2022 |
| --------| -------- | -------- |
| A       | xxx      | xxxx     |
| B       | xxx      | xxxx     |
| C       | xxx      | xxxx     |

I want to make line chart (filter by country) (with data from column Pop 2021-2023)
So we can see the trend

How to do that?

I dont know what to do to make it like that